# How can I dynamically remove a parent in JSON with JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-tables-2

With some JavaScript, how can I transform a JSON from:

```
{
  "d": {
    "__count": "13",
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "123"
        },
        "COAST": "East",
        "STATUS": "done",
        "COLOR": "blue",
      }
]
}
}
```

TO

```
{
    "__count": "13",
    "data": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "123"
        },
        "COAST": "East",
        "STATUS": "done",
        "COLOR": "blue",
      }
]
}
```

Basically removing the extra "d" parent and renaming results to data? I am using this in the context of vue-table in VueJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed that you have the json saved in a variable 'data':

```
data = data.d
data.data = data.results
delete data.results
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will do it.

```
function transform(json) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
  obj.d.data = obj.d.result;
  delete obj.d.result;
  return JSON.stringify(obj.d);
}
```

Comment: The parsing and re-stringifying seems unnecessary? (Especially since it's an object, not JSON.)

Comment: json is text, not a javascript object

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to unserialize your JSON to have an object (JSON.parse()). Then to serialize only what you need (JSON.stringify()).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a loop.

```
var res = [];
for(var k in jsonData){
    res.push(jsonData[k]);
}
```

```js
var jsonData = {
  "d": {
    "__count": "13",
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "123"
        },
        "COAST": "East",
        "STATUS": "done",
        "COLOR": "blue",
      }
]
}
};

console.log(jsonData);

var res = [];
for(var k in jsonData){
    res.push(jsonData[k]);
}
console.log("result:");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why? You're creating an array (not asked for) and not creating a `data` key.

Comment: @DaveNewton I assumed that's not a single node.

Comment: Why? Either way, still missing 1/2 of the question :)